# PHP floor() weird behaviour

Tags: php, debugging, floor

When floor-ing a result of a multiplication I get a different result than when floor-ing a normal number. Is this behaviour expected? If yes, why?

```
$val1 = 29;
$val2 = 0.29*100;

echo floor($val1); // prints 29
echo floor($val2); // prints 28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of floating point precision in PHP, in your example:

`gettype($val1);` returns `integer`

and

`gettype($val2);` returns `double`

Combine that with this warning on php.net:

> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....

taken from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

And we can see why your floor takes it from 28.9999999999 etc down to 28, instead of the integer 29 to 29.

Comment: Just at the same. Serendipity exists!  ;)

Comment: Thank you! Accepted because you commented on my code and provided a quote.

Answer (score 3):

It is part of PHP weird precissions. It's normal depending on the machine.

> > Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision
> >     format, which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in
> >     the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give
> >     larger errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered
> >     when several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118….
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.

http://techiedan.com/2013/10/11/php-floor-function-float-value/

Comment: Good answer, thanks! However, accepting the other answer as he comments on my example.

Comment: Sorry @manuelbcd I think those were milliseconds apart, I'll upvote you

Comment: Thanks Chris. I did the same so it's clear that I'm agree with your solution.  Moreover, as Chris said, you added detailed example.  Your answer is better.